# How to split data vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I want to cluster and split (using Hadoop) a dataset with some 60K features (dimensions a.k.a. columns). This dataset has very few instances -- about 100 rows.  Instead of splitting data horizontally, I want to split according to feature clusters.  For instance, if I get 3 clusters, I want each cluster to have 20K columns and 100 rows, to run on 3 different nodes.

How to achieve this kind of split?  Failing that, can you provide any suggestions for a framework other than Hadoop to facilitate this split?

Comment: What kind of operations are you going  to perform on your dataset ? Is the operation to be performed is column wise operation and you don't need the full record( row) in the same mapper ?  In what format is your dataset available ?

Comment: The dataset is in csv format. yes the operations are like finding entropy of a feature , so it will be column wise, I dont need full record in same mapper.

Comment: Parquet file format might be of a help for you. It has a columnar storage layout. Mapreduce jobs can read a particular column fro the same and apply operations from the same. You can google more about it

Comment: Tightened wording.

Comment: Is transposing the csv an option for you?

Comment: i also considered that as one of the option.. but it means like.. transpose the data... split it and again take transpose to get back data in original form... and the data is say a matrix of some 100 rows and 30K-40K columns, so i think complexity will be increased in that case.

Comment: Hadoop is not the way to go for a dataset that fits on a single machine. Write a python script or similar if it's less than 10TB. You can fit that kind of data on a single desktop machine.

Comment: Yes, now i understands that i should not use Hadoop , but then, can you suggest me a way to reduce execution time.. which will be better,, multi-threading or GPU ( I want to execute same code on each part of data or on each thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: with this *tiny* data set (60k*100 that is a few megabytes), MapReduce is a very bad choice. You get massive overhead, at zero benefit. **Don't use Hadoop if your data fits into main memory!** Even Excel will be faster.

Apart from that, you can obviously convert from row storage to column storage by *mapping* switching your row and your column identifiers:

```
def map(key, row):
    for column, value in row:
        send( column, (key, value) )
```

Comment: I have read somewhere that hadoop is used for parallelization of data while multi threading is for process parallelization. I have to divide data into say 3 parts and to apply same algorithm on 3 parts. To reduce the overall time I want to do it on hadoop. Can I use multi threading for the same ( for data parallelization ) ??... or what can be the other possible option?